# How do I build a Cocoapod framework for swift, while keeping implementation details hidden?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am trying to build an iOS swift framework to display encrypted photos. Photos are sent by my server (something like a hashed binary file) after calling a specific API with specific details. I will then decrypt the photo, and display it to the user.

Correct and point me in the right direction if I am wrong, but swift only allows frameworks - meaning no static library. And this will expose my implementation details (such as the method to decrypt my photo).

What I would like to achieve is to create a cocoapod distributable framework for paid developers to implement (once they subscribe to me). It is supposed to expose simple public APIs, and hide implementation details.

I have tried various ways to achieve that but to no avail. I would really like to keep the implementation to swift codes only, with minimal Obj-C codes.

1. Build a swift framework, and build an objective-c static library as a wrapper

> But I cannot seem to get it to work. Any idea if this is possible?

2. Build a swift framework in a swift framework

> Stupid idea, i'm able to see the framework's implementation details within the other framework...

1. Build a swift framework, and build an objective-c framework as a wrapper

> I cannot seem to get this to work either...

I have been working on this project for about 2 weeks now, and have been all over Googling for it. Just in case anybody would like to try, you may try to do the following and check if it works.

- Cocoapods Friendly Framework
- Implementation Details Hidden
- Uses Alamofire (or any public framework that connects to internet)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Security is not obtained by hiding "implementation details (such as the method to decrypt". The security is in a good encryption method such as AES,  in a good scheme and the key. Also it is not easy to include Common Crypto in a framework, search for solutions on SO. What implementation details are you seeing in a Swift framework? As above the method is not something that needs to be hidden.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. Indeed it is not obtained by simply hiding. However, a more detailed scenario of what i'm trying to do is that the photo will be split up into a variable sized grid, encrypted, then send to the phone, and the phone ultimately decrypt it, and then forms the received bits of photo back into the whole image again. I would like the hide the part where I am forming back my photo, as it's algorithm based.. Any ideas?

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): "any person can invent a security system so clever that she or he can't think of how to break it." It always amazes me the amateurs always think their algorithm is better than proven security methods. Consider that the whole electronic funds transfer industry is based on well known algorithms. So, have you prepared your "mea culpa" for when the scheme is broken? Because if one relies on a secret method when it is discovered all is lost. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. I will rethink my approach on this, and enforce it with better ways! (: